# Subscribe method on http.get observable: what is the third argument?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I use subscribe method on observable (result of http.get) in Angular 2 final version. While the first argument of the subscribe method is function which gets data from backend, the second one is function which is executed on error (like status http code 404), I don't understand meaning of the third argunent/function.

In hope it is executed *always* when the request has ended (with either success or error), I remove/stop loading indicator in it, but the third function is not called on error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third callback is called when the observable is completed. This means that the observable will not emit any more events.
Currently the observables returned by `Http.xxx` calls only emit one single event and are completed afterwards, therefore the 1st and 3rd callback are called at the same time (one after the other) but `Http` could change to eventually emit more than one event, then the 1st callback is called for every event, and the 3rd callback is called once after the last event.

Comment: So I could get one of these: 1,3 OR 2,3, but 3 is called anyway?

Comment: One of 2 or 3 should always be called once after the last event. In case of a success 3 is called, in case of a error only 2 (but not 3) is called.

Comment: So I must stop loading indicator in 1 and also in 2. How can I remove this duplicity?

Comment: You can use the `finally` operator. This operator is called once in any case (after 2 or 3).

Comment: Where is finally operator defined?

Comment: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/finally'`

Comment: Thanks Günter Zöchbauer ! Someone needs to update this answer including the precisions in the comment because the answer in itself is not that clear

Answer (score 7):

The third argument of every sequence is the complete handler. It is invoked with no params and just notifies the sequence finished.

```
Observable.from([1,3]).subscribe(
  (v => console.log('value: ', v)),
  (e => console.log('error: ', e)),
  (() => console.log('the sequence completed!'))
```

would print:

value: 1

value: 2

the sequence completed